# Can I save ipython command line history to a notebook file?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I was using iPython command line interface and after some operations I want to save my operation history to a notebook file. But I was not using iPython notebook from the beginning. Can I still make it?

Comment: You can: `%notebook -e myhistory.ipynb`

Comment: @ThomasK this actually needs to be an answer. the accepted answer doesnt reflect reality! you start reading it and you get the impression its not gonna work! I tested it and it works prefectly!

Comment: `%notebook my history.ipynb` is required with current versions of `python`--see the [magics docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-notebook)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From @Thomas K (I don't know why he didn't post an answer):

```
%notebook -e myhistory.ipynb
```

Comment: Drop the `-e` with [current versions](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-notebook) of `python`.

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is **in a couple of ways**, the slightly longer answer is **Yes - but you might not get what you expect!**

Really long answer: The explanation is that when you are working in a notebook, *now called a jupyter notebook of course,* your work is stored in a series of cells each of which has one or more lines of code or markdown while when you are working in a console all of your work is a series of lines of python code.

From within a console session you **can** save, using `%save` some or all of your work to one or more python files that you can then paste, import, etc, into notebook cells.  You can also save using `%save -r` to `.ipy` files your work including the magics as magics *rather than the results of magics* that again you can use from within your notebook later.

You can also use the `%notebook` magic to save all of your current history in one of an `ipynb` *json* file or a python `.py` *text* file *with the -e export flag*.  However, it is not clear from the documentation if the history will end up in a single cell, one cell per command or some other division.  A little testing suggests one cell per numbered line of your console, so a single command or definition, per cell.

Personally I will stick with outputting anything useful into python files using the `%save` command - or better yet start a notebook when I think I might be doing something that I would need later.

Comment: Sorry Steve, but the *right* answer is yes. ;-) The `%notebook` magic is for precisely this use case. E.g. `%notebook -e myhistory.ipynb`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jupyter console (ie, the command line version of jupyter notebook) you can use the following command within a cell to *save the notebook as a python file (.py)*

```
save yourfilename
```

this will save the contents of the notebook as **"yourfilename.py"** in your current working directory (from which you started the jupyter console)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can save the whole program by this command :

```
%save -r program-name 1-999999
```

The following commands were written to file program-name.ipy